# How to underline text in a question or answer?

Tags: support, formatting

I have searched around the question box and the help center, I have found [this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) in the "formatting tips" but haven't found anything that allowed you to underline text.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underline is used for hyperlinks. It is not possible to add underline formatting to other text. If you want to emphasis something, use **bold** or *italics*.